# Unable to commit or push using GIT in pipeline job - Could not create directory '/home/SYSTEM/.ssh'

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins Master and running the jobs on a Windows Slave. I am trying to push my commits to my git repo but doesn't work as expected

Below is my Pipeline script

```
{node('win2k12') {
def artifactTagVersion = params.TAG_VERSION
if(artifactTagVersion) { // groovy treats null or empty strings as false
    print "Building in Release mode for version: ${artifactTagVersion}"
    // create flag to define that release mode is active
    isRelease = true
    } else {
        print "Building in SNAPSHOT mode"
    }

stage("Checkout & Use git"){
    deleteDir()
    checkout scm
    if(isRelease){
        print "Preparing sources for releasing."
        // go into headless mode
        bat "git checkout --detach HEAD"
        bat "echo v${artifactTagVersion} > versionFile.txt"
        def commitMessage = "Release for version ${artifactTagVersion}"
        sshagent(['a075b609-adaf-233d7f3be0a0']) {
            bat "git add ."
            bat "git commit -m \"${commitMessage}\""
            bat "git tag -a v${artifactTagVersion} -m \"${commitMessage}\""
            bat "git push origin v${artifactTagVersion}"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error i get while building

```
E:\jenkins\slave\workspace\test-job-trainex---dev---ts>git push origin v1
Could not create directory '/home/SYSTEM/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have no clue, tried searching a lot for this but no one has answer on why does this look for a directory and keys when its a windows machine and the path looks like linux.

Comment: The issue was more about ssh keys that need to be forwarded to the windows slaves to avoid command prompt each time git fetch is executed on the slaves. My solution was to store ssh keys on slaves without passphrase and i use java web start method to launch the windows slave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the issue, the problem is with the windows slave. So while we setup the windows slave we do set it up as a service.
While we set the windows service its better always to configure it with credentials.

- Open services(run->services.msc)
- Open properties for jenkins_slave process
- click on tab "Log on"
- Instead of System account, configure under "This account"
- Stop and start the service again

Also instead of cygwin, install git bash which will work for the sshd services. That's it and now everything works.